# How do I implement framework function touchDown in a turnbased loop?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm using a simple turn based loop, switching between player turn and enemy turn. In the player turn the `loop` should "pause" until `framework function` `touchDown` has been activated, then pass the turn to the enemy. I'm not sure how to implement this as `touchDown` triggers automatically whenever you press the screen.

Am I to use an `observer` of some sort or a `#selector`? Tried both unsuccessfully, but that may just be for my lack of experience. If I use the `selector` the `loop` doesn't pause to wait for the screen to be clicked. As for the observer, I'm just not sure how its implemented. I also tried just adding the whole `touchDown` method into the player turn but that obviously didn't work.

The `loop` simply looks like this:

```
var state = "PLAYER"
func runGame() {
    while(gameIsProgressing) {
        if(state == "PLAYER") {
            print("Player is doing stuff")

            //THE touchDown METHOD SOULD BE TRIGGERD HERE

            state = "ENEMY"

        }else if(state == "ENEMY") {
            print("\nENEMY IS DOING STUFF")

            state = "PLAYER"
        }
    }
}
```

Also, it is important that `touchDown` is triggerd only in the player turn, and not whenever the screen is pressed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are programming something with a GUI here, you should not think in this imperative way. There is no (good) way to "pause" a while loop "until" something happens.  You should think in a more event-driven way.

Instead of thinking about the while loop, think in terms of the events that happen. In this case, the event is `touchDown`. Note that I don't know of a library function called `touchedDown` (did you mean `touchesBegan` or is this an action for a `UIControl`?), but I'll assume it exists. When the player touches the screen, what do you want to happen? Well, probably something like this:

```
    guard gameIsProgressing else { return }
    if(state == "PLAYER") {
        someFunctionThatShowsWhatThePlayerDid()

        state = "ENEMY"
        print("\nENEMY IS DOING STUFF")

        someFunctionThatMakesTheEnemyDoStuff(completion: {
            self.state = "PLAYER"
        })
    }
```

Comment: Ah, yes, I see. I was thinking about it the other way around... sort of. I completely understand what you mean and have a pretty sound idea now on how to implement it. Thanks for taking the time!